# Can you change the font family of ContentEditable text to a custom font using execCommand in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I have some code:

```
function SelectedValue() {
    var e = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(strUser == "TypeWriter"){
       richTextField.document.execCommand('fontName',false,"'TypeWriter'");
    }else if(strUser == "Komika"){
       richTextField.document.execCommand('fontName',false,"\'Komika\'");
    }else{
       richTextField.document.execCommand('fontName',false,strUser);
    }
    document.getElementById("dropdown2").style.fontFamily=strUser;
}
```

This code change the text to a font like Arial or Times new roman and that works fine. But when I try to set it to a custom font like Typewriter it dosnt work it just goes to the default font. I know the fonts are correctly installed because they work when setting the font family of other html elements like

and . Is it possible to change the font family of text using execCommand to a custom font in javascript?

Here is all relevant code:

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Komika';
    src: url('KOMTITA_.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('KOMTITA_.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('KOMTITA_.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('KomikaTitle-Axis.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('KomikaTitle-Axis.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
    url('KomikaTitle-Axis.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TypeWriter';
    src: url('1942.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('1942.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('1942.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('1942report.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('1942report.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
    url('1942report.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

HTML

```
 <center><div id="WYSIWYGBTNS">
                <select onchange="SelectedValue()" name="fonts" id="dropdown2" class="dropdown_class" style="margin-top:0px;display:inline-block;">
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Lucida Console"style="font-family:'Lucida Console';">Lucida Console</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="TypeWriter" style="font-family:'TypeWriter';">TypeWriter</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="arial"style="font-family:'arial';">Arial</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Impact"style="font-family:'Impact';">Impact</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Times New Roman"style="font-family:'Times New Roman';">Times New Roman</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Courier New"style="font-family:'Courier New';">Courier New</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Webdings"style="font-family:'Webdings';">Webdings</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Century Gothic"style="font-family:'Century Gothic';">Century Gothic</option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Georgia"style="font-family:'Georgia';">Georgia </option>
                  <option id="dropdown_item" value="Komika"style="font-family:'Komika';">Komika </option>

                </select>
</div></center>

          <center><iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField"  style=""><div style=""><?php echo $text;?></div></iframe></center>
```

Javascript

```
function SelectedValue() {
    var e = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(strUser == "TypeWriter"){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('fontName',false,"\'TypeWriter\'");
    }else if(strUser == "Komika"){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('fontName',false,"\"Komika\"");
    }else{
    richTextField.document.execCommand('fontName',false,strUser);
    }
    document.getElementById("dropdown2").style.fontFamily=strUser;
}
```

Comment: Make sure the font is spelled properly. I could see no escape characters for type writer font, but you have used it for Komika. I don't know the reason. And try using Courier font.

Comment: i tried using escape characters but that isnt working :(

Comment: Did you try the Courier font?

Comment: I suspect the name "TypeWriter". These stuffs are case sensitive. Try reinstalling the type writer font or install different type writer fonts and use them.

Comment: My suggestion would be using "Courier" font, because it is a built-in font residing in your OS

Comment: none of that worked

Comment: try to post the complete code

Comment: @Venky its been updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your custom font-face inside the iframe in order to work correctly.